# GROUP BY problems in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to Google Big Query (and Stack Overflow), mainly testing the speed at which Big Query manages to process both well-crafted and poorly-crafted queries.

I'm having difficulty with a cumbersome query that runs (slowly) on MySQL. Big Query complains about the GROUP BY contents. Here's the starting query:

```
SELECT nonstops.term, nonstops.lincat, nonstops.id, 
MIN(
(1-((LEAST(1,minusone.catimp / nonstops.catimp) + LEAST(1,minusone.catweb / nonstops.catweb))/2))*
(1-((LEAST(1,minusone.catimp / nonstops.catimp) + LEAST(1,minusone.catweb / nonstops.catweb))/2))*
(1-((LEAST(1,minusone.catimp / nonstops.catimp) + LEAST(1,minusone.catweb / nonstops.catweb))/2))*
(nonstops.catweb * nonstops.catweb * nonstops.catimp / nonstops.fnvweb / nonstops.fnvimp)
)
AS calc FROM nonstops INNER JOIN EACH minusone ON nonstops.lincat = minusone.lincat AND nonstops.term = minusone.term 
WHERE nonstops.lincat = 556 GROUP BY nonstops.term, nonstops.lincat
ORDER BY `calc`  DESC
```

Note that "EACH" is added to the INNER JOIN as both tables are big. I have removed the dataset name to make it easier to read.

The GROUP BY is intended to return just the lowest value of the calculation that is made by the join for each term/lincat pair.

The error I get is:

**(L1:62): Expression 'phrases.nonstops.id' is not present in the GROUP BY list**

Which I don't want in the GROUP BY, but I've added it and I then get:

**Expression '`calc`' is not present in the GROUP BY list**

Which I also do not want! But if I add it I get:

**(L7:1): Cannot group by an aggregate**

I have looked at the documentation and searched for an answer, but no luck. Any hints or links would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When you group by something in BigQuery (or any SQL) the resulting fields should be either group-by fields or aggregations.

Otherwise, which value of nonstops.id should you get? There might be many associated with a pair of (nonstops.term, nonstops.lincat).

You could select max, min, etc of id field instead; group by this field (but then you get calculation for each tuple of term, lingcat and id); or just remove this field if you don't need it - if you want the result of 'calc' expression for each (nonstops.term, nonstops.lincat) pair.

The reason BigQuery complains about `calc` is different - BigQuery (when you use legacy SQL dialect) does not use backticks (`) for quotation. So it thinks they are part of the name and it is a new field separate from 'calc' field. Just remove them or use BigQuery's quotations [ and ] - `[calc]`. Or switch to standard SQL dialect.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the backticks were indeed a problem. The missing id field from the GROUP BY is a good point, for this data it works fine in MySQL as the results are known to produce the same id for each grouping (a little redundant but index on id is used). I changed it as suggested and it worked.

Comment: Should add, performance wise, it took 75 seconds (2.5GB data). Splitting the query up into a JOIN (producing a set of data) then running GROUP BY takes 20 seconds and then 15 seconds. A Linux box with 32GB 2133Mhz RAM, 8GB used by MySQL a pretty slow AMD A10 processor (7850K) with data on a Samsung 840 SSD took around 2000 seconds for the full query or splitting them.

Comment: Performance-vise I think you could benefit by doing filtering before JOIN (BigQuery is not smart enough to do it on its own yet):

SELECT ... FROM 
(SELECT .. FROM nonstops WHERE lincat = 556)
INNER JOIN EACH 
(SELECT .. FROM minusone WHERE lincat = 556)
ON nonstops.lincat = minusone.lincat AND nonstops.term = minusone.term 
GROUP BY nonstops.term, nonstops.lincat
ORDER BY calc  DESC

Comment: Thanks again Michael, should have made it clear that the lincat = 556 was removed from the query for those stats, so all calculations were needed. Your suggestion is a very handy tip for performance enhancement, I am starting to see that BigQuery is awesome, but it has quirks. Well worth learning, and even better if kind people take their time to point the quirks out.